# Python remove whitespace at end of CSV file

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a Django view which reads a CSV file and saves it to a model.

**views.py**:

```
def csv_upload(request):
    ...
    file = request.FILES['attach']
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';') 
    next(reader) # skip headers

    for line in reader:
        ... # process and save
```

**EDIT**

Traceback:

```
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/bin/datazone/climate/views.py" in climate_upload
258.                 report.year = line[1]

Exception Type: IndexError at /climate/upload/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

**END EDIT**

Whilst testing with file variations, I noticed that if there is trailing whitespace in the file (e.g. empty rows due to saving form Excel) I get an `Index out of range` error.

My question is, how can I strip the whitespace from the end (and probably the begining just to be sure) of the file.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: could  you post the exact traceback  you  recieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if my understanding is correct, you want to take care of some blank lines in the end of the file, right?

```
for line in reader:
    if line:
        ... # process and save
```

Thanks @dm03514 for pointing out a mistake in my original answer

Comment: This worked for me: `if ''.join(line) == '':continue`. Are there any problems with using this solution?

Comment: @DarwinTech Yes that will work. Or, you can use the one in my updated answer, which is more concise I guess

Comment: This is unecessary why would you call a function when you can just check if the line is empty or not? `if line:`?

Comment: @dm03514 you're right, I thought the csv reader function did the same thing to empty line as `split()`, fixed

Comment: @xvatar - So I used `if not line: continue` which fits into the flow nicely and deals with any line which happens to be empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`line` will be a list.  You cannot strip it.  If it is an empty list that means it is an empty line in your file.Just check that lines has elements in it.  An empty row will not have any list elements.

Instead of stripping lines you can just check that the line is valid `if line:`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `line.strip()`?

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: that gives me  `'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: yes, line is a list, not a string. if u r using the whole list as a parameter u can create a strip_list function.

Answer (score 0):

Line is a list, not a string. if you are passing the whole list as a parameter you can create a strip_list function.

```
def strip_list(my_list):
    for index, string in enumerate(my_list):
         try: my_list[index] = string.strip()
         # In case it's not a string
         except AttributeError: pass
    return my_list

for line in reader:
    line = strip_list(line)
```

Or you can strip each item when you use it.

```
line[0].strip()
```

Comment: `line[0].strip()` doesn't solve his problem it will raise the same error;